# Writing to users policy registry key

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I want to be able to write values into a users policy key located in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\ - but this location can only be written to by an admin user.

I have both an application running as the user and a service on the system that I control. I'd like for the app to tell the service which user it is logged on as and for the service to then go in and write to that users policy section.

What is the best way to do this? Impersonating the user? Can I just clone the users token and send it accross to the service or is there a way to find the full path from HKEY_USERS to the users policy section?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not only can this key only be written by an administrator, but also this key actually contains network policy settings. If you need to change these values, use the policies manager on your domain server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what I did in the end:

1. Find current users SID in the application (OpenProcessToken, GetTokenInformation, ConvertSidToStringSid)
2. Pass the string SID to the service
3. Make changes to HKEY_USERS{SID}\Software\Policies

Answer (score 1):

User profiles are organized within `HKEY_USERS` by the user's "Security Identifier." This security identifier can be obtained by iterating through `ProfileImagePath` keys within `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`. (User accounts start with `S-1-5-21`. This links usernames to security identifiers. You can then access the user from `HKEY_USERS` using the obtained security identifier.